# Parsing XML Data Results in FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, nodes

I'm attempting to parse the following XML data:

```
<response>
<cmd>getPosts</cmd>
<success>1</success>
<NumberOfSongs>4</NumberOfSongs>
<Posts>
<Post>
<Title>Stream</Title>
<Video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/bNXqZR0A2Mw</Video>
</Post>
<Post>
<Title>Movies</Title>
<Video>http://www.youtube.com/embed/bNXqZR0A2Mw?rel=0</Video>
</Post>
<Post>
<Title>Music</Title>
<Video>none</Video>
</Post>
<Post>
<Title>Hello world!</Title>
<Video/>
</Post>
</Posts>
</response>
```

However every time I do so I'm getting a NPE:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.androidbegin.xmlparsetutorial.MainActivity.getNode(MainActivity.java:110)
```

I've attempted to connect to the web service then parse the data using the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare variables
    TextView textview;
    NodeList nodelist;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Insert image URL
    String URL = "http://exampleurl.com/xmlrpc.php?cmd=getPosts";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Locate a TextView in your activity_main.xml layout
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute(URL);
    }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("Android Simple XML Parsing using DOM Tutorial");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                // Download the XML file
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                // Locate the Tag Name
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("cmd");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    // Set the texts into TextViews from item nodes
                    // Get the Success
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Success : "
                            + getNode("success", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the NumberOfSongs
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "NumberOfSongs : "
                            + getNode("NumberOfSongs", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the Posts
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Posts : "
                            + getNode("Posts", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");
                    // Get the Title
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Title : "
                            + getNode("Title", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
                            + "\n");
                    // Get the Video
                    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Video : "
                            + getNode("Video", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
                            + "\n");                    
                }
            }
            // Close progressbar
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // getNode function
    private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

I believe the issue lies with my element nodes - but I can't seem to figure out exactly what it is.

P.S.

Line 110: is `.getChildNodes();`

### LOGCAT:

```
01-17 17:30:07.373: W/ResourceType(17573): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
01-17 17:30:07.483: D/libEGL(17573): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-17 17:30:07.493: D/libEGL(17573): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-17 17:30:07.493: D/libEGL(17573): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-17 17:30:07.503: D/(17573): Device driver API match
01-17 17:30:07.503: D/(17573): Device driver API version: 10
01-17 17:30:07.503: D/(17573): User space API version: 10 
01-17 17:30:07.503: D/(17573): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
01-17 17:30:07.543: D/OpenGLRenderer(17573): Enabling debug mode 0
01-17 17:30:07.838: D/AndroidRuntime(17573): Shutting down VM
01-17 17:30:07.838: W/dalvikvm(17573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ff42a0)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.androidbegin.xmlparsetutorial.MainActivity.getNode(MainActivity.java:110)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.androidbegin.xmlparsetutorial.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:108)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.androidbegin.xmlparsetutorial.MainActivity$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:85)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.androidbegin.xmlparsetutorial.MainActivity$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-17 17:30:07.843: E/AndroidRuntime(17573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 17:30:20.528: I/Process(17573): Sending signal. PID: 17573 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

`eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag)`

or

```
getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
```

Might return null. You can figure it very easy using debugger. Set up your break point on 110 line and press 'go into' on that line when your debugger is hang on that line.

Comment: It is returning null (I knew that before I posted this - I'm trying to figure out WHY it's returning null in order to resolve the NPE)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to call the method .getChildNodes() on a Null object. For instance, when you call the function getNode here

```
// Get the Video
textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Video : "
    + getNode("Video", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
    + "\n");
```

your empty video tag may cause

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
```

To return Null, as Rafik991 mentions.

Try fixing it by checking for null before using the return value of the method.

Comment: It is returning null (I need to figure out what is causing it) but in the meantime would this seem correct?   if (nValue.getNodeValue() = null) {
   Log.e("getNodeValue is Null", e.getMessage());
  } else {
   return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }